# Wildfly org.jboss.nio -> FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path with Windows Java JDK 11.0.15+10

Tags: java, windows, jboss, wildfly

Since the update to *Eclipse Tamurin* *JDK 11.0.15+10* we notice a problem as soon a HTTP request reaches Wildfly 20.0.1.Final. The same behaviour exsists in Wildfly 26.1.0.Final This only happens with the *JDK* Windows version, the Linux *JDK* works fine.
As it is an "Invalid file path" error, an OS dependent BUG seems possible.

Until now SAP Machine is the only JDK that does not encounter this failure.

I'm still not sure if this is a *JDK* or a *Wildfly* problem...

You can check that when opening the *Wildfly Management Interface*.

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /management}: java.io.IOError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.1.Final//org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:1103)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.1.Final//org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:1093)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.1.Final//org.xnio.channels.Channels.<clinit>(Channels.java:1093)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.io.UndertowOutputStream.write(UndertowOutputStream.java:231)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.writeBuffer(BlockingSenderImpl.java:245)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.writeBuffer(BlockingSenderImpl.java:238)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.send(BlockingSenderImpl.java:75)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.io.BlockingSenderImpl.send(BlockingSenderImpl.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainUtil.writeResponse(DomainUtil.java:89)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler$1.doSendResponse(DomainApiHandler.java:177)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.ResponseCallback.sendResponse(ResponseCallback.java:32)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:232)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.lambda$handleRequest$0(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:62)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.12.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:328)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.12.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:285)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:254)
    at org.jboss.as.controller@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:225)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-http-interface@12.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.ElytronIdentityHandler.handleRequest(ElytronIdentityHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
    at io.undertow.core@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:231)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:126)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.1.Final//org.xnio.channels.Channels$4.run(Channels.java:1098)
    ... 29 more
```

| JDK | Works with Wildfly |
| --- | --- |
| Eclipse Tamurin | no |
| Amazon Coretto | no |
| Azul Zulu | no |
| Bellsoft | no |
| Oracle OpenJDK | no |
| Oracle JDK | no |
| SAP Machine | yes |

Comment: This is also discussed here, if someone has a Red Hat subscription: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6953431

Comment: Related to [JDK-8285445](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8285445) (Cannot open file "NUL:", JDK 11.0.15 on Windows), perhaps? In that case it could maybe be mitigated by setting up a logging file-handler to "NUL" (without the colon). Scheduled to be fixed in 11.0.16.

Comment: Thanks @RolKau for finding this. I would accept his as an answer if you post it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue in the JDK. You can wait for JDK 11.0.16 or downgrade to a lower version like JDK 11.0.14.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a [known JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8285445). You can work around the issue by setting `Djdk.io.File.enableADS` system property. In Intellij go to Run -> Edit configurations and paste `-Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true` in VM Options field.

Answer (score 0):

you can use open-jdk 11.0.20+, its works for me in wildfly

https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads?field_java_parent_version_target_id=406&field_operating_system_target_id=436&field_architecture_target_id=391&field_java_package_target_id=396